# react-bootstrap component generates error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've seen some other issues with react-bootstrap but not my specific error so I hope my post passes the moderation rules about duplicity.  I am trying to learn react and I want to use bootstrap for CSS only.

I copied the table code from [react-bootstrap documentation site](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tables) into my component.   When render is called I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: TableLayout.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be
>   returned.

My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap';

console.log("render TableLayout 2");

class TableLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return 
        <div>
            <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
            </Table>
        </div>
    }
}
export default TableLayout;
```

and I invoke that through my app.js as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import TableLayout from './TableLayout.jsx';

render(
    <TableLayout />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this implementation?

Thank you
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error states, you're not actually returning anything, as your JSX neither starts on the same line as the `return` statement, nor is wrapped in parenthesis. Right now Javascript interprets your `render()` method as:

```js
return; // returns nothing

<div>
  ...
</div>
```

Try this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```